# JavaScript - href not working in addEventListener / innerHTML

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I am stuck on a problem while making a simple website. What I want to achieve is that on the home page when I click the bootstrap navbar item 'Follow Us On', a button appears with the href to [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com).

I have achieved the button appearing through addEventListener on clicking the item, and toggling/removing it by clicking again. However the problem is that the href is not working.

The code for href, which I am injecting using innerHTML, works fine on codepen.io, however it is not working in the website. Any idea why this is so?

## html code

```
    <!-- Nav Bar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark flex-column ">
                   
        <button
          class="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-bs-toggle="collapse"
          data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="aboutlnd.html">ABOUT L & D</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="ourprojects.html">OUR PROJECTS</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#cta">CONTACT US</a>
            </li>
            <li id="follow_us" class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">FOLLOW US ON</a>
                
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <div id="blank_space" class="nav-link"></div>
                
                
              </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

## Js code

```
var follow_toggler = document.getElementById("follow_us");



// function to be called and removed when button is clicked
function noscroll(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("blank_space").innerHTML = `<button  type="button"   class="btn  btn-dark  btn-lg  download-button">
    <a  href="https://www.facebook.com/"  target="_blank"> <i  class="fa-brands  fa-apple"></i>Facebook</a> </button>`;
   
    
}

// TOGGLE EVENT LISTENER
var scrollToggle = false;

function toggleEventListener() {
    if (scrollToggle === false) {
        window.addEventListener("click", noscroll, false);
        scrollToggle = true;
    } else {
        window.removeEventListener("click", noscroll, false);
        scrollToggle = false;
    }
}

follow_toggler.addEventListener("click", function () {
    toggleEventListener();
}, false)
```

Comment: An anchor (`<a>`) element (which is an "interactive content")  [isn't allowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#technical_summary) to be inside of a button element.

Comment: @Ivar - Thanks, it really increased my understanding. However, the problem still persists. Now I am using this as innerHTML: `<a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank" class="btn  btn-dark  btn-lg  download-button" role="button"><i  class="fa-brands  fa-apple">
    </i>Facebook</a>`


Interesting thing is, the same button if put directly in the html file, works perfectly fine.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working". Doesn't it open a new page at all? [Because it should work fine](https://jsfiddle.net/ozhfj98v/). (Although in the linked example, it will show a "blocked" page, because Facebook isn't allowed to open from iframes.)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly happens i.e. no page is opened at all.

Comment: Even in this Jsfiddle if you paste the complete javascript code I gave above, then you'll see that it doesn't work.